# Can you use the word "Concomitant" as a synonym for "Coworker"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns

I am writing a novel and I recently discovered this word.

From my understanding, the definition sounds broad enough to be able to use this word loosely in place of co-workers.

For Example:

> With everyone sitting, it was difficult to see Angie, but after a minute or two, her pretty, little head popped up between my ***concomitants***, and I did my best to suppress my smile.

Concomitants, of course, taking the place of co-workers.

The occupation is a politician (Councilman) in a radical Christian dystopian - his co-workers, of course, are also politicians as well.

If this is not correct, I will most likely go with "colleagues" despite wanting something more unique. "Comrades" has a negative connotation to it and words like "associates" and "peers" sound too vague and bland.

Comment: Nobody can stop you from using this word, but if you want people to readily understand what you mean, I would advice against it. The word is rare enough by itself, and this meaning is certainly non-standard. You seem to imply that those coworkers are somehow a necessary (and negative) side effect of the character.

Comment: I would be very, very careful about describing a woman as having a "pretty little head." It reeks of sexism, as in "Don't you bother your pretty little head..."

Comment: You say that "the definition [of *concomitant*] sounds broad enough" - but what definition are you referring to?  You need to expand your Q. to include that info  and explain **why** you think that.

Comment: As an aside, in British English we don't use "Coworker” either!

Comment: I would use "colleagues," "fellow staffers," or "workmates" before I would use "concomitants" as a synonym for "co-workers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concomitant doesn't mean co-worker,  but  by  extension, it may refer to a thing or a person that happens to be next to you in a specific time or context:

[Concomitant](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/concomitant)
(noun):

> - a concomitant act, person, etc

(Collins Dictionary)